# Redux - time travel for side effect such as service connection

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I'm using redux-thunk and starting to see some limitations.

Suppose I have actions `PUSHER_CONNECT`, `PUSHER_CONNECTED`, `PUSHER_DISCONNECTED`, `PUSHER_LISTEN_TO_CHANNEL`, `PUSHER_MESSAGE_RECEIVED`, etc. The state would have something simple that indicates the connection status.

```
{ connection: 'connected' } // OR
{ connection: 'disconnected' }
```

How would I be able to **truly** travel back and forth between these 2: `PUSHER_CONNECTED`, `PUSHER_DISCONNECTED` since the pusher connection is still living somewhere. I was thinking of keeping the pusher object and related objects in the state and if it's `PUSHER_DISCONNECTED`, set them to `null`. But there's no guarantee those objects are immutable.

Another thought is that, I would add a check for `PUSHER_MESSAGE_RECEIVED`: if `state.connection !== 'connected'` then don't push the new message... simulating that it's a "real" disconnection. Similarly, add a check for `PUSHER_CONNECT`, if the pusher object is there and connected, don't re-connect but just change the state to `{connection: 'connecting'}`

How would you approach this?

Comment: What kind of time travel are you talking about? Redux DevTools? They only change what the app sees as the current state but don’t affect the side effects. Why do you want to change the side effects?

Comment: yes Redux DevTools. I just want to know if it's possible to have a way to revert back and forth side effects so it is truly "time traveling". If I go back to the state where I haven't connected to Pusher, but the connection is still there, that's not really time traveling. Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the store and manage something like a “two way binding”.

In the listener, check the status, and if it contradicts the store state, execute the necessary effects. Be careful not to get into an infinite loop there.

This is the approach https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux takes for synchronizing the URL bar on time travel.